# How to compare date and weeknumbers?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get an query to see the total amount of invoices to paid per week when paying invoice at 60 days after receiving.

The query I have is running without problem but the results can not be correct.
What might be causing the unexpected result?

In the query below I am trying to get the total amount of invoices to be paid in week 52/2015 with the invoice date of 60 days before week 52.

```
SELECT
SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM invoices
WHERE date_paid = '0000-00-00' AND WEEK(DATE_ADD(date_recieved, INTERVAL 60 DAY)) = 52 AND YEAR(DATE_ADD(date_recieved, INTERVAL 60 DAY)) = 2015
```

When using 30 and 60 days I have the result, but the total should be around 364k.  (Don't mind the forst row, it's an different query)

[image]

Comment: 60 days!!! Whose T&Cs?

Comment: It is good to know what happens with the cashflow determing this at 30 / 60 / 90 days!